# How do I output image in the loop for an entry?

Tags: assets

I've run into an unexpected situation, where ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string.

```
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3) %}
{% for news in news %}
    {% set cover = news.promotionNewsImage %}
    {% if cover|length %}
        {{ cover.getUrl('gtLg') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any thoughts on that please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image input returns and array so you need to reference the first item, even if you only allowed one to be selected.

```
{% set news = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3) %}
{% for news in news %}
   {% set cover = news.promotionNewsImage %}
   {% if cover|length %}
       {{ cover[0].getUrl('gtLg') }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That has solved my problem, only when I run it outside `<style type="text/css">@media (min-width: 1200px){.news{code}}</style>`. I thought, that neccesary markup will not affect the output. I may post my code here, but I feel like it's another question. What do you say?

Comment: You may need to post that separately that seems different to what you asked above.